# Css rule application order

Tags: css, color-scheme

This post (even though it is based on a fact that causes me trouble in my work) is more of a philosophical questioning rather than a real issue submission.

I tumbled across this following puzzling case ...

It is not really an issue as I (think I) understand this phenomenon, how it is ruled and the effects it has.

I made the following example : http://jsfiddle.net/q7xAn/ as descriptive as I could.

In this case, why (Ô gods why) the span has a yellow background ?

I don't wonder which rule applies it but more of : in the name of which twisted (as in opposed to what I always assumed) does the last declared rule applies over the first declared one ?

I mean that ".red span" and ".yellow span" have the same complexity.

- Same length
- Each item at a given position has the same weight/importance

They are equivalent in css selector natural order.

Then what should prevail in the matter of which applies is which rule stick the closest to the styled item.
In the case of my example, the span should be styled with '.red span' (closest rule) rather than by '.yellow span' (which is correct too but is 'overridden' by '.red span').

Are there any 'historic', 'political', 'philosophical' or any other reason for this behaviour ?
Can some DOCTYPES (may be ?) that might force the behaviour I am looking after ?
May I submit request to w3c (why not ?) ? how ?
Any information, advice, different point of view, is more than welcomed !

Thanks all in advance.

---

```
Edit note :
```

I hate to quote myself but in a comment to aymeric, I figured a good way to explain what my questioning really is about.

---

In general what bother's me is that If I have, let's say 7 color-schemes (one for each rainbow color).

Also assume that I am the css maker of a team of (let's say) 10 persons.

I want them (my team) to be able to nest color-schemed blocks.

- In one case a red coloured block would hold a yellow and a magenta block.
- In an other (interesting) case, one would want to have 7 levels of nesting (red nested in orange nested in yellow nested in ...).

I have no way to now about which use the will need beforehand.

Current CSS experienced behavior would force me to revamp my css **every** time a new *nesting* need pops out and to end up with obnoxiously overly bloated rules.
In terms of maintainability this is an atrocity :'(

Comment: Sorry! But I really couldn't suppress a smile after reading the wordings of your post :)

Comment: Not sure if you smile because you like the way I write or because making fun of my approximate english (I'm french). Anyway glad I made you smile ;)

Comment: One reason may be that if the browser simply applied the latest applicable rule, then it would not have to keep track of the cascading order of each and every element.

Comment: I smiled 'cause I appreciate the way you framed your question. Not 'cause of your English.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that it is entirely dependant on the order of the rules in the CSS. Since the span is enclosed in both .yellow and .red, it would be consistent with the behaviour of css. The rule that applies to it, that appears last in the css would be the style that it took. Swapping the order of the rules makes the element red. I've not tested in more than 1 browser, but unlike applying multiple classes to an element (which has an undefined order of rule application - browser vendors can do as they please), I haven't seen text that indicates this behaviour to be undefined. :shrug:

Comment: Agree. I tried reversing the position of the styles and the effect was just the reverse. It is the order that is taken into consideration. I ended up computing the specificity of the rules but they are same. I was going through W3C's rules for this, but I'm not sure which one applies in this case.

Comment: @verisimilitude : Thanks for the framing compliment ;) And for the specificity, I know, that is the base of my problem, for same specificity, the choice that has been made for the next way to settle which rule applies makes no sense to me if one want to build a "css declaration order agnostic" page/site.

Comment: @enhzflep : that very 'undefined' thing is my problem here. CSS is supposed to be ruled by conventions, if not it is not a reliable tool anymore (I intentionally exaggerate here)

Comment: @AlexanderChen : That would make sense to save up memory/computation time, but imho it makes no real logical sense (on an architectural/organisational dimension)

Answer (score 2):

Its known as `specificity` of css. And if two selectors match to a particular element and they have the same `weight`, the selector that appears `later` applies to the element.

Read [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for more info.

Your selectors `.red span` and `.yellow span` both have the weight of `0,1,1` (the link I mentioned will explain in detail how to calculate the weight) and so the last rule is applied.

Also read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.htm) article from W3 which will explain things better.

Hope all that made some sense :)

Comment: Thanks, it all already made sense to me and I perfectly understand that yellow takes over red since it is declared after. But in a comment to Aymeric's post I described better what my problem fundamentally is. "Current CSS experienced behavior would force me to revamp my css every time a new need pops out and to end up with obnoxiously overly bloated rules."
Hope I make more sense now, but anyway, thanks for the reply.
This article will help me be more accurate in my understanding an apprehension of how browser compute rules that I take for 'naturally' granted :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/css-101-handling-multiple-rules-for-the-same-element/6164216) (not really recent but explicit) which explains (if I didn't misunderstood your questions) answers your looking for.

For example, if you replace:

```
.red span, .red{
background-color: #F00
}
```

by:

```
.yellow .red span, .red{
    background-color: #F00
}
```

Your background will be red.

Regards.

Comment: Yes that would work and I already knew that ;). But I'm not looking there at a way to solve a problem or to understand how CSS behaviour is implemented but rather at a way to understand why it is implemented that way. An extra bonus would be discovering an other implementation (maybe doctype dependant) that I can force for my page that allows the behaviour I am looking for. Anyhow, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: In general what bother's me is that If I have, let's say 7 color-schemes (one for each rainbow color).
I am the css maker of a team of (let's say) 10 persons.
I want them to be able to nest color-schemed blocks.
In one case a red coloured block would hold a yellow and a magenta block.
In an other (interesting) case, one would want to have 7 levels of nesting (red nested in orange nested in yellow nested in ...).
I have no way to now it beforehand. Current CSS experienced behavior would force me to revamp my css every time a new need pops out and to end up with obnoxiously overly bloated rules.

Comment: The only way to do it which pops in my mind is defining css 'root classes' according to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7xAn/11/) and nest those in html